# draw rect from another class

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i have two classes on different xibs, one has the window and a slider (controller 1), the other has a window and a view (controller 2).  controller 1 is files owner of the first xib and controller 2 is a class of a NSView.  What I want to do is when I move the slider I want to change the color of the NSRect.

In controller 1 I have my slider action:

```
-(IBAction)moveSlider:(id)sender
{
    Controller2 *view = [[Controller2 alloc] init];
    [view redraw];
}
```

and in controller 2 I have my draw rect and my method to redraw.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        RectColor = [NSColor blackColor];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) redraw
{
    NSLog(@"changed");
    RectColor = [NSColor blueColor];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}


- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [RectColor set];
    NSRectFill(rect);

}
```

the weird thing is when i have my action and the slider on the same xib as my view with the draw rect it works just fine.  however when I have the slider in the other xib it wont work. any ideas? thanks!

Comment: In `moveSlider:` action method, you are creating `Controller2` everytime. Is that the case required?

Comment: well i dont believe its required, i imported that file but this was just the only way i knew how to call methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Controller1 the `moveSlider:` method creates a new instance of Controller2 every time it is called. Controller1 needs to keep a reference to the existing Controller2 and call the `redraw` method on that instance.

Comment: ok that definitely makes sense but how would I code that? sorry i am new to xcode and from what I have looked up would i need a delegate or how could I do that?

Comment: Exactly how depends on your application. One way would be to add a property to `Controller1` of type `Controller2` and have whatever object creates `Controller2` set it.